# how to return customized json as output in Springboot JPA?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities responsible for fetching data from two different tables and i have created a class to display the combined result of those two entities. I am able to fetch the data using JPA but the output is not in the desired JSON format.

First Entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="basicinfo")
public class Rfx_BasicInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String uniqueid;

    private String description;
    private String uniqueidstatus;
    private LocalDateTime startdate;
    private LocalDateTime enddate;
    private String createdby;

    public String getCreatedby() {
        return createdby;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUniqueid() {
        return uniqueid;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStartdate() {
        return startdate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public String getUniqueidstatus() {
        return uniqueidstatus;
    }

}
```

and the Second one,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="supplierinvite")
public class Rfx_SupplierInvite {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String externalstatus;
    private String uniqueid;

    public String getExternalstatus() {
        return externalstatus;
    }

    public String getUniqueid() {
        return uniqueid;
    }
}
```

These two are the repositories for the entities i created.

```
@Repository("rfxBasicInfoRepository")
public interface Rfx_BasicInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<Rfx_BasicInfo,Long> {
    @Query(value="SELECT u from Rfx_BasicInfo u where u.createdby = :createdby")
    List<Rfx_BasicInfo> findReportByLoginId(@Param("createdby") String createdby);
}


@Repository("rfxSupplierInviteRepository")
public interface Rfx_SupplierInviteRepository extends JpaRepository<Rfx_SupplierInvite,Long> {
    @Query(value="SELECT u.uniqueid, u.externalstatus, count(u.externalstatus) from Rfx_SupplierInvite u  where u.uniqueid in (:uniqueid) group by u.uniqueid,u.externalstatus order by u.uniqueid, u.externalstatus")
    List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> findReportByUniqueId(@Param("uniqueid") String uniqueid);
}
```

In the first repository i'm fetching the data based on the "createdby" field and in the second one i'm fetching the data based on "uniqueid" field. This "uniqueid" field is common between the two tables. As of now, i have tried to fetch the results separately and merge them into one using a class. I didn't use any JPA mapping and Joins because i'm not sure how to use it here properly.

```
public class Rfx_Model {

    private List<Rfx_BasicInfo> rfx_basicInfoList;
    private  List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> rfx_supplierInviteList;

    public Rfx_Model(List<Rfx_BasicInfo> rfx_basicInfoList, List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> rfx_supplierInviteList) {
        this.rfx_basicInfoList = rfx_basicInfoList;
        this.rfx_supplierInviteList = rfx_supplierInviteList;
    }

    public List<Rfx_BasicInfo> getRfx_basicInfoList() {
        return rfx_basicInfoList;
    }

    public List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> getRfx_supplierInviteList() {
        return rfx_supplierInviteList;
    }


}
```

This is my controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buyerLandingReport/{LoginID}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> buyerLandingReport(@PathVariable("LoginID") String LoginID) {
        try{

            List<Rfx_BasicInfo> list1 = rfxBasicInfoRepository.findReportByLoginId(LoginID);
            List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> list2 = rfxSupplierInviteRepository.findReportByUniqueId(list1.get(0).getUniqueid());

            return new ResponseEntity(new Rfx_Model(list1,list2),HttpStatus.OK);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Below is the current JSON ouput,

```
{
    "Rfx_BasicInfo": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "uniqueid": "RA001",
            "description": "sbhdjajd",
            "uniqueidstatus": "ajsd",
            "startdate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "enddate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "createdby": "RIL01"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "uniqueid": "RA001",
            "description": "kasksj",
            "uniqueidstatus": "sjkds",
            "startdate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "enddate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "createdby": "RIL01"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "uniqueid": "RA002",
            "description": "asjhkdj",
            "uniqueidstatus": "asjhd",
            "startdate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "enddate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "createdby": "RIL01"
        }
    ],
    "Rfx_SupplierInvite": [
        [
            "uniqueid": "RA001",
            "externalstatus":"AC",
            "count": 1
        ],
        [
           "uniqueid": "RA001",
           "externalstatus": "IN",
           "count": 2
        ]
    ]
}
```

and the desired JSON ouput format is this one,

```
[
    { 
        "Rfx_BasicInfo": {
            "id": 1,
            "uniqueid": "RA001",
            "description": "Auction for taking bid for work on route Tirora Gondiya",
            "uniqueidstatus": "PB",
            "startdate": "2018-05-04T12:00:00",
            "enddate": "2018-05-04T14:00:00",
            "createdby": "RIL03"
        },
        "Rfx_Supplier" : [ 
            {
                  "uniqueid": "RA001",
                  "externalstatus": "AC",
                  "count": 1
            },
            {
                  "uniqueid": "RA001",
                  "externalstatus": "IN",
                  "count": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        "Rfx_BasicInfo": {
            "id": 2,
            "uniqueid": "RA002",
            "description": "Auction for taking bid for work on route Gondiya  -  Amgaon",
            "uniqueidstatus": "DR",
            "startdate": "2018-05-04T14:00:00",
            "enddate": "2018-05-04T16:00:00",
            "createdby": "RIL03"
        },
        "Rfx_Supplier" : [ 
            {
                  "uniqueid": "RA002",
                  "ExternalStatus": "AC",
                  "count": 1
            },
            {
                  "uniqueid": "RA002",
                  "ExternalStatus": "IN",
                  "count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions to help me figure out the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You really need the `ResponseEntity` ? If not, the common way is:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/buyerLandingReport/{LoginID}")
    public Rfx_Model buyerLandingReport(@PathVariable("LoginID") String LoginID) {
        try{

            List<Rfx_BasicInfo> list1 = rfxBasicInfoRepository.findReportByLoginId(LoginID);
            List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> list2 = rfxSupplierInviteRepository.findReportByUniqueId(list1.get(0).getUniqueid());

            return new Rfx_Model(list1,list2);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't really help me in generating the desired JSON format as i described above. I'm getting the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Controller as

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buyerLandingReport/{LoginID}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> buyerLandingReport(@PathVariable("LoginID") String LoginID) {
    try{

        List<Rfx_BasicInfo> list1 = rfxBasicInfoRepository.findReportByLoginId(LoginID);
        List<Rfx_SupplierInvite> list2 = rfxSupplierInviteRepository.findReportByUniqueId(list1.get(0).getUniqueid());

        List<Rfx_Model> body = Arrays.asList(new Rfx_Model(list1, list2);
        return new ResponseEntity(body), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

You need to return a list (or array) to get a json array response.